# Canoo and Groovy - how to use storeRegEx

Tags: grails, groovy, canoo

We would like to test the following flow using Canoo. The tests are written in Groovy, and not as Ant tasks.

1. Send a request to a specific URL (we use "invoke")
2. Extract specific information from the response (we use "storeRegEx" with property:"ans")
3. Print the extracted value (for debug purposes). println "${ans}" - does not work
4. Use the extracted value in the next action (e.g. invoke "new/url/id=#{ans}")

We saw some references to using an AntBuilder, it fails as well.
Is there some example for that flow?
Thanks

Comment: Independently of your test, make sure your regex actually works the way you think it does with the input URL.

Answer (score 0):

remember that it depends on the ant property type (dynamic or ant) whether you have to use `#{ans}` or `${ans}`

println will not work in webtests. Use the description property of webtest steps instead:

```
group(description:"#{ans}") {
     ...
}
```

this will show you the value of your property in the test result.